# Can i build vocaburay in twice with gensim word2vec or doc2vec?

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim, doc2vec

I have two different corpus and what i want is to train the model with both and to do it it I thought that it could be something like this:

```
model.build_vocab(sentencesCorpus1)
model.build_vocab(sentencesCorpus2)
```

Would it be right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: each time you call `build_vocab(corpus)`, like that, it creates a fresh vocabulary from scratch – discarding any prior vocabulary.

You can provide an optional argument to `build_vocab()`, `update=True`, which tries to add to the existing vocabulary. However:

- it wasn't designed/tested with `Doc2Vec` in mind, and as of right now (February 2018), using it with `Doc2Vec` is unlikely to work and often causes memory-fault crashes. (See https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1019.)
- it's still best to `train()` with all available data together - any sort of multiple-calls to `train()`, with differing data subsets each time, introduces other murky tradeoffs in model quality/correctness that are easy to get wrong. (And, when calling `train()`, be sure to provide correct values for its required parameters – the practices shown in most online examples are typically only correct for the case where `build_vocab()` was called once, with exactly the same texts as later calling `train()`.)